# Cmder all text same colour

Tags: terminal, cmder

Im using [cmder](http://cmder.net/) windows terminal but I but all the text is the same colour regardless of command, or output etc. Can it be different colours to make it easier to read? IE

[image]

I can change the theme in settings etc but think im in the wrong place.

Answer (score 5):

You were on the right track...

On that screen (Settings > Features > Colors), there will be a dropdown for Text like so:

[image: Change color of text in Cmder]

Select the option that best suits your needs for legibility.